# How can I use XmlNode and XxmlNodelist in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I have class was written by C#, It used XmlNode and XmlNodelist to read XML file.
But When I bring it to my WP8 project, It's didn't support XmlNode and XmlNodelist.
What should I do ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do?

You should use LINQ to XML ([`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument) etc) instead. It's a far superior XML API. Once you've ported your code to use it, ditch the `XmlNode` (etc) code entirely - use LINQ to XML in both your desktop and mobile code. Unless you really need to use .NET 3.0 or earlier, you should (IMO) try to avoid ever using `XmlDocument` and friends again.

(Some of the types like `XmlReader` are used in both the old and new APIs - but the DOM types themselves are completely separate.)

Comment: Thank you Jon. But I wanna to use the Nodelist to access every item in Xml file.

Comment: @Carson: Why do you want to use `XmlNodeList`? Why not use LINQ to XML to access every item in the file? Surely your ultimate goal has nothing to do with using `XmlNodeList` - surely it's about "doing something with each node" which is easily achievable with LINQ to XML. Concentrate on the end result, not the mechanism you happen to use at the moment.